# how to add an element to an array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

How would I add an element to an array, assuming that I have enough space? My code looks something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    ofstream out("hi.out");
    ifstream in("hi.in");
    string currentLine;
    string values[135];/*Enough for worst case scenario*/
    if (out.is_open && in.isopen()){
        while (in >> currentLine){
            /*Add currentLine to values*/
        }
        /*Do stuff with values and write to hi.out*/
    }
    out.close()
    in.close()
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't. Use a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an index counter variable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    ofstream out("hi.out");
    ifstream in("hi.in");
    string currentLine;
    string values[135];/*Enough for worst case scenario*/
    int index = 0;
    if (out.is_open && in.isopen()){
        while (in >> currentLine){
            /*Add currentLine to values*/
            values[index++] = currentLine;
        }
        /*Do stuff with values and write to hi.out*/
    }
    out.close()
    in.close()
    return 0;
}
```

The variable `index`, once the loop is complete, will contain the number of strings in your array.

Answer (score 4):

No need to write the loop yourself. With your array:

```
auto l = std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(in), {}, values);
```

`l - values` is the number of strings read.

Or even better, use a vector, so that you don't have to worry about the possibility of your "worst case scenario" not being the actual worst case scenario.

```
std::vector<std::string> values(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(in), {});
```

Comment: I am not really that good at C++, could you explain more to me what this does?